# What is the most efficient way to check each line up to a certain character

Tags: php, parsing

If I pipe an email into a PHP script, and go through each line using `fgets`, what is the best way to filter out the values from the `From:` `To:` and `Subject:` lines?

I was thinking about exploding each line at `:` and then checking `if ($result[0] === 'To')` and so on, but then I'm exploding each line, when I should only be doing that for `From`, `To` and `Subject`

From a Google/SO search I found `substr()` but you need to specify the number of characters to search, which is different for each value I want.

Comment: I think the best manner by using regular expression. By using regular expression you can filter out anything as you want.

Comment: you can use regular expressions for that

Comment: @Lion King Except HTML. Anything but HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a page out to parse mail headers - They are sharing their regular expressions they are using, so maybe you can simple grab the parts you need:

http://mailheader.mattiasgeniar.be/headers.php

The Regular Expressions suggested for your desired fields are:

```
From     |^from:(.*)|mi 
To       |^to:(.*)|mi 
Subject  |^subject:(.*)|mi
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella added the expressions in question.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
$finds = array('Subject:', 'From:', 'To:');
$founds = array();

$line = fgets(...); // whatever your logic is to get each line

foreach($finds as $key => $find){

    if (substr(trim($line), 0, strlen($find)) == $find){
        $founds[] = array($find, $line);
    }

} 

print_r($founds);  // you can explode (or whatever) the data as needed
```

this is untested, i just typed it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions do something like this, for each input `$line`:

```
$matches = array();
$params = array();
if (preg_match('/^Subject: (.*)/', $line, $matches) == 1) {
    $params['subject'] = $matches[1];
} elseif (preg_match('/^From: (.*)/', $line, $matches) == 1) {
    $params['from'] = $matches[1];
} elseif (preg_match('/^To: (.*)/', $line, $matches) == 1) {
    $params['to'] = $matches[1];
}
```